# Overlap while scrolling in WebView

Tags: android

I have an rss feed (xml)  where I have a embedded youtube link with tag iframe.

I have a WebView where I have loaded the XML. I am able to play the youtube link by the inbuilt flash player but the problem is while playing if I scroll down or up the WebView, the flash player overlaps the WebView and other layout whereas it should be within the WebView

Any suggestions on this please.

Here is the xml youtube link

```
<IFRAME height=350 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0PqQNr570Ro" 
        frameBorder=0 
        width=650 
        allowfullscreen>
</IFRAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

Redraw your webview when scroll.

Tell the scroll view's content view to post bounds changed notifications, then listen for `viewBoundsDidChangeNotification`